# RESTful version of common Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, rest

I've used this "good old" way to fetch HTML formatted data via Ajax and inject it into the DOM.

`http://localhost/ajax-controller/mobile-view/resource/1/`

```
$mobile_view = new View('mobile-view'); // use mobile view
$mobile_view->data = $this->data_array; // add some data to view
$this->response->body($mobile_view);    // return formatted HTML
```

`http://localhost/ajax-controller/web-view/resource/1/`

```
$web_view = new View('web-view');       // use normal web view
$web_view->data = $this->data_array;    // add some data to view
$this->response->body($web_view);       // return formatted HTML
```

Question is **What is the RESTful version of this?**

Should I fetch just JSON data via Ajax?

`http://localhost/ajax-controller/resource/1/`

```
$this->response->body(json_encode($this->data_array)); // return JSON data
```

How should I handle view / HTML formatting, another ajax request? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is fine to have views in restful services, as determining how to return data.  I would suggest passing a url parameter like

```
http://localhost/ajax-controller/resource/1/?view=mobile
```

and figuring out how to respond via that parameter

Comment: So RESTful isn't just a data and could be the final HTML version?

Comment: RESTful implies a url that defines a resource.  in this case 'resource/1'.  the way of displaying that view does not need to be a part of that url definition, so you can make it a url parameter.  EDIT: unless of course the view actually effects the resource (which seems odd).  in that case it should be part of the url like in your code.

Comment: The purist REST approach is to use a resource URL and an accept-encoding header to determine the format of the returned data.